# Why is SwiftLint whitelist_rules not working on my project?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftlint

I'm trying to configure swiftlint in my project and `white_list` is not working.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

my `.swiftlint.yml`:

```
whitelist_rules:
  - force_cast: warning
```

my code:

```
let forceCast: Int = "hue" as! Int
```

which gives me the error:

> Force Cast Violation: Force casts should be avoided. (force_cast)

when I expect it to give me only a warning, not an error. Beyond this example, no other rule is working when on `whitelist`.

I know swiftlint is reading my `.swiftlint.yml` because I tested it with `disabled_rules` and it seemed to be working fine, so it's not a matter with the path of my `.swiftlint.yml` file.

Also, for the record,

- I have configured correctly the Run Script Phase
- I am not using `whitelist_rules` along with `disabled_rules` and `opt_in_rules`, I'm using only `whitelist_rules`.
- I'm using swiftlint version 0.40.3, xcode 11.3, ios 13.2 and swift 5

What am I missing? Why isn't it working?

Comment: I don't think you can configure a rule on the same line where it's being added to the whitelist. Try removing the `: warning` here, and then on another line (outside of the whitelist rules) say `force_cast: warning` to configure the rule, and see if that works.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone had recent issues with `whilelist_rules` configuration key, notice that it was renamed to `only_rules` in version 0.41.0

https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/releases/tag/0.41.0